# X11 window desktop display problem on HDMI screen on ROS Kinetic+Debian Jessie arm64

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, debian, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tested three tf cards and they all had the same problem:
After the card just being enabled **Debian Jessie arm64** in it , I executed *"startx &*" and the hdmi display was able to show the x11 desktop. However, after I operated for a while, if I rebooted it and executed the command "*startx &*" again, the gui desktop couldn’t be displayed on the screen, the serial terminal would log such errors:

```
root@linaro-alip:~#startx &

X.Org X Server 1.17.3
Release Date: 2015-10-26
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.2.0-16-generic aarch64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux linaro-alip 4.9.51-imx_4.9.51_imx8m_ga+g6df7474 #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 12 12:13:52 CDT 2018 aarch64
Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200 earlycon=ec_imx6q,0x30860000,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw
Build Date: 29 February 2016  07:27:03PM
xorg-server 2:1.17.3-2.linarojessie.2 (http://www.debian.org/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat May 21 22:34:39 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

For the first two cards, I’ve done too many operations(included installing ROS Kinetic package), so I’m not sure which operation caused this phenomenon. For the third time, I just installed **ROS Kinetic desktop full** packages,then installed and compiled two demo packages, and then I executed “*$ reboot*” and "*$ startx &*", the same phenomenon and the
same error log occurred again.

I only met a similar situation that ros installation might cause desktop fail to start on **Ubuntu16.04+Ros Kinetic+Vmware12** . As long as I installed ros and rebooted ubuntu ,it would remind me “The system is running in low graphic mode” and failed to start the desktop. My solution is replacing Vmware12 with **Virtualbox** at that time. I don't know whether there are relations between the two situations.

I’m not sure if this is a Debian problem or a Ros problem or my board(i.MX 8M) problem. I didn’t encounter such kind of situation on **Ubuntu14.04+Ros Indigo+i.MX 6ull(my previous board) / Vmware12, Debian Jessie+Ros Kinetic+Vmware12, Ubuntu16.04+Ros Kinetic+Virtualbox** .

In addition,My sd card's memory size is 16GB, and the installation of ros kinetic desktop-full package only takes less than half of the memory, so this may not be the reason for the lack of memory.

So,Does the installation of ros affect the X11 configuration? What is the specific impact? How should I avoid and solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289681/x11-window-desktop-display-problem-on-hdmi-screen-on-ros-kinetic+debian-jessie-arm64/) by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, I've found the reason,  it's not a ROS problem, it's my own board's bug, thanks!

---

Originally posted by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-27**:
It would be good if you can provide a little more detail as to what is/was the actual problem. That way future readers could use your answer to their advantage.

**Comment by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on 2018-05-14**:
It was because that I’d like to enable camera on my board in order to test ros demo on board, I copied the modules folder in directory “/lib/kernel” of Yocto directly to Debian board, then, though the usb camera could be recognized and used normally, the desktop couldn’t start.